# Finding xpath location on a new window, opened after click. Using java, and selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am practicing UI automation testing through using java and selenium. My goal is to locate web elements in most efficient way possible.

The code below is what I use to find the (xpath) location and click on an active link after visibility.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(path))).click();
```

After click I am supposed to locate another web element on the new scene. Regularly if webpage leads me to next scene on the same window this code is helpful.

When click causes a new window to open my code fails because of 'TimeoutException'. I tried to find ways but the web page I am working randomly changes the way. Some times next page comes in the same window and some times new window opens.

Is there a proper way to go about to solve this type of problem?

Comment: Have you tried handle new window?

Comment: The scenario you are describing is not clear. Are you saying the script executes the exact same steps on the exact same link and whether a new window is opened or not is inconsistent? More description, maybe some screenshots, maybe some HTML would help clarify.

Comment: If new window or tab is opened, you need to switch driver to the new window/tab.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some conditions exist in your application making it either open the new page in the same or different window.

First task would be to identify that condition.As your web element is not visible it is throwing exception after waiting for pre-configured time given in the explicit wait.

Second,is then

1. If it is same window, it would be bit straightforward, as there will be no window to switch to.you could use explicit wait as we you were doing with the first element.
2. If it is opening in a new window, try to switch to that window and then perform your action. Selenium provide this support. Refer following link for that: [Link](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames)

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'handler' to manage windows.

Some web applications have many frames or multiple windows. Selenium WebDriver assigns an alphanumeric id to each window as soon as the WebDriver object is instantiated. This unique alphanumeric id is called window handle. Selenium uses this unique id to switch control among several windows. In simple terms, each unique window has a unique ID, so that Selenium can differentiate when it is switching controls from one window to the other.

**GetWindowHandle Command**
Purpose: To get the window handle of the current window.

```
String  handle= driver.getWindowHandle();//Return a string of alphanumeric window handle
```

**GetWindowHandles Command**
Purpose: To get the window handle of all the current windows.

```
Set<String> handle= driver.getWindowHandles();//Return a set of window handle
```

SwitchTo Window Command
Purpose: WebDriver supports moving between named windows using the “switchTo” method.

```
 driver.switchTo().window("windowName");
```

**Or**

Alternatively, you can pass a “window handle” to the “switchTo().window()” method. Knowing this, it’s possible to iterate over every open window like so:

```
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {

driver.switchTo().window(handle);}
```

**Or**

Switching between windows with Iterators:

```
 driver.findElement(By.id(“id of the link which opens new window”)).click();

 //wait till two windows are not opened

 waitForNumberofWindowsToEqual(2);//this method is for wait

 Set handles = driver.getWindowHandles();

 firstWinHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); handles.remove(firstWinHandle);

 String winHandle=handles.iterator().next();

 if (winHandle!=firstWinHandle){

 //To retrieve the handle of second window, extracting the handle which does not match to first window handle

 secondWinHandle=winHandle; //Storing handle of second window handle

//Switch control to new window

 driver.switchTo().window(secondWinHandle);
```

Details here: https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/switch-commands/

Comment: Thanks for your input and the link. I am very new on Selenium's Window Handling aspect and still practicing. It will be a good source for my studying. What I try is to sign in to my account and update it. I do it to get more fluent using Selenium and practicing to use more efficient xpath locations.  I have tried this in several web pages that I have account. Some of them  are harder because of the reasons  I mentioned in my question.  Also thank you for all responses.